# Film that begins with spaceship combat seen from a cockpit or control room

Tags: story-identification, movie

Alright, so as a kid I remember seeing the beginning of a film on TV, and it's been bugging me for more than a decade trying to figure out what it was.

I remember the first scene - it felt like late 70s - early 80s budget VFX - flat lighting, visible matte lines, maybe even still images of models animated.

It started with a dogfight. I remember an x-shaped ship. There was a cockpit or control room shot. Very claustrophobic, darkly lit with the glow off of computer screens being the most lighting.

That's about all I can remember. Had a name evocative of Dark Star I think, but it isn't Dark Star. It's not Star Wars either.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year or decade did you actually watch this?

Comment: Please confirm you're not actually talking about _Star Wars_ (1977).

Comment: Nope, not star wars. Probably saw it in the 00s?

Comment: Did it look like a [Starfury](https://babylon5.fandom.com/wiki/SA-23E_Mitchell-Hyundyne_Starfury)?  (https://www.youtube.com/watch/v=sVhUcFgev-Q)

Comment: Starcrash? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YU5sF1u0XHU - The fight near the start was quite evocative of Star Wars.

Comment: *Babylon 5* has X-shaped fighter ships, and the first season has rather primitive CGI.

Comment: Way, way, way back there was "supermarionation" stop-motion animation series Fireball XL5  https://youtu.be/-yKFrI7KDxc?t=42        If that's even a vague possibility I'll fill it out as an answer.

Comment: https://youtu.be/ST7QrlLLtLI?t=26 X makes me think of X-Bomber, or Starfleet as it was known in the UK as. Great Japanese show. Not too flat lighting though, quite moody.

Comment: Not Babylon 5, doesn't seem like Starcrash.

Comment: Possibly one of the 1980's Battlestar Galactica "Films"? The extended pilot episode got a theatrical release and later on several episodes were edited together and released to cinema's as Mission Galactica: They Cylon Attack. Lots of dog fighting, definitely visible mat lines, darkly lit control room, take a look at this and see if anything seems familiar... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E2BJodHVGT8

Answer (score 9):

A possible answer, especially if the memories are a bit hazy, is *The Last Starfighter*. Released in 1984, so the graphics tie in with your recollection. The main ship is broadly x-shaped, although less obviously so than an X-wing.

I don't believe the opening scene is a dogfight, but the protagonist (Alex) playing the video game is an early scene, before he is recruited to the Star League to become a gunner in reality.

Comment: Such an excellent film! I hope this is correct

Comment: Nah, not The Last Starfighter either. That's why this is bugging me so much. I *know* sci fi. And I caaaaaaannot figure this one out.

Answer (score 2):

Might be B-movie producer Roger Corman's attempt to cash in on the first Star Wars wave of success. The Battle Beyond the Stars (1980). Written by John Sayles  and Directed by Jimmy T. Murakami. There's a cockpit scene from the evil command ship at the start.  The plot circles around a peasant boy from a  peaceful planet that is under threat of invasion from the forces of an evil overlord. The boy takes his ship and goes off into space to find adventurers and experienced warriors to fight for his cause against the evil. There are plenty of spaceships, one of the smaller ones has an x-figure shape.

BATTLE BEYOND THE STARS (1980) Official Trailer - YouTube

Answer (score 1):

Could this be "Deep Red" (1994) https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109589/ which (from memory) starts with a space battle from which an alien ship survives, crashes to Earth, and then ends up embedded in a child's hand? The rest of the movie is evilcorp trying to capture the child to harvest the life-extending alien nanotechnology.